# Sending a file to a webservice with XML using cURL corrupts it

Tags: php, curl

So I have some code that sends a career application to a webservice which then emails the file  to the hr department as an attachment along with other elements in the form. All of the parts except for the file gets emailed as desired. The file gets uploaded to the server without being corrupted. But the resulting email attachment ends up being corrupted.

The problem is; the file ends abruptly before reaching EOF. Let's say it is a pdf file when I open both the original and the reduced size file in a text editor I see that the beginnings are identical until one of them suddenly ends. One of them is about 1MB and the corrupt one is about 600kB.

I have tried sending files smaller(4kB) than the resulting corrupt file but that file also gets corrupt in the same way. The resulting file is about 1kB.

The xml response I get says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SENDEMLRSP><RTCD>1</RTCD><EXP>OK</EXP><RSP_LIST><RSP><MSGID>0</MSGID><EID /><RESULT>Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.</RESULT></RSP></RSP_LIST></SENDEMLRSP>
```

It is this part that is of interest:

```
<RESULT>Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.</RESULT>
```

I have prepared a small form with only a file upload for testing purposes.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>

    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the relevant PHP code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']))  
            {
            echo ($_FILES['file']['name']);
            echo ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            $target = $_FILES['file']['name'];


            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);

            $rawdata = file_get_contents($target);

            $data = urldecode($rawdata);
            $data = base64_encode($rawdata);


            //error_log('uploadconvertscope');


            $iletisimrcpt = '<RCPT>
                           <TA>someemail@address.com</TA>
                           <MSG>kgsg</MSG>
                           <SBJ>'. strlen($rawdata).'</SBJ>
                           <OBOE>'.OBOE.'</OBOE>
                           <OBON>'.OBON.'</OBON>
                           <ATT_LIST><ATT><FN>'.$_FILES['file']['name'].'</FN><DATA>'.$data.'</DATA></ATT></ATT_LIST>
                  </RCPT>';


          $request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
               <SENDEML>
                   <VERSION>1.0</VERSION>
                   <TOKEN>'.$token.'</TOKEN>
                   <JID>'.JOBID.'</JID>
                   <MSG>Kariyar Basvuru isteði baþarýyla yerleþtirildi.</MSG>
                   <SBJ>Kariyar Basvuru</SBJ>
                   <RCPT_LIST>
                   '.$iletisimrcpt.'
                   </RCPT_LIST>
               </SENDEML>';
        error_log($request );
        $params = array('data' => $request);

        $response = processRequest(EML_URL, $params);

        error_log($response );
        $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($response);
        }
```

The processRequest function works with the rest of the message. So it may not be the problem but here is the code:

```
<?php

        function processRequest($url, $params) {

        if(!is_array($params))

        return false;

        $post_params = "";

        foreach($params as $key => $val) {

        $post_params .= $post_params?"&":"";

        $post_params .= $key."=".$val;

        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // 'true', for developer testing purpose

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_errno($ch))

        print curl_error($ch);

        else

        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;

        }

        ?>
```

The file when read as a string between the looks like AHFAY3453GAW//LONG RANDOM STRING OF CHARACTERS//==  it always ends with two "==" signs if that means anything.

I am really stumped as the files get uploaded OK with this C# code:

```
        byte[]  attach1 = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\amb.pdf");
        string attach = Convert.ToBase64String(attach1);
        EmlRequest.SetConnectionInformation("someapi.com", "admin", "password");
        EmlRequest eml=new EmlRequest(){  MessageJobId="DASFA1SDFAWEFA4X2==" };
        eml.Recipients.Add(new ApiEmlRecipient() { TargetAddress = "email@address.com" ,ToName="name",Message="xxx",Subject="subject"});
        eml.Recipients[0].Attachments.Add(new ApiEmlAttachment() { FileName = "abm.pdf", Data = attach });
        eml.Send();
```

Which is almost identical to it's PHP version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out quite some time ago but only got down to writing an answer.

So the problem was that the "+" signs in the string were replaced by spaces.

This bit was responsible:

```
$rawdata = file_get_contents($target);
$data = urldecode($rawdata);
$data = base64_encode($rawdata);
```

I changed it to this:

```
$rawdata = file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
$data = base64_encode($rawdata);
$data = urlencode($data);
```

Now it works.